# how to unset permision folder html

Tags: php, linux, chmod

In my Linux machine i have html folder and projects are inside this folder.Now i can't edit my projects its locked like

[image]

now i can't directly edit or delete pages.i wan to login as root .so it's very difficult for code changes.totally stuck and i did

```
sudo chown shanu /var/www/html
```

how can i unset this permissions?please help me

Comment: "_i wan to login as root_" Ugh, why? Why not log in as a regular user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give permission to html folder 777 like

sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html